# What the difference between those two?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between these two:

```
var test1 = function () {
    this.method1 = function() {}
}
```

and

```
var test2 = function() {};
test2.method1 = function() {};
```

Comment: Yes. Syntax error: `var test2 = function();`

Comment: @diolemo I fixed the syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet takes `this` object, whatever it is, and assigns a function to its slot (field) named `method1`. `this` can represent different objects, depending upon how `test1` is called:

- when called as a standalone function -- `test1()` -- `this` will be `window`
- when called as a constructor -- `new test1()` -- `this` refers to the object being created
- when called via `call` or `apply` -- `test1.apply(someObject)` --  `this` refers to the argument

The second snippet takes the object `test2` and assigns a function to its slot named `method1`.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is a constructor that creates more objects and needs to have the `new` keyword:

```
var mytest1 = new test1();
mytest1.method1();
```

The second way is ready to use right away:

```
test2.method1();
```

Comment: Note that `test1` is not necessarily a constructor.  It could be used as one, but it could also be intended to run in the context of an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming syntax was correct, the first is a constructor that gives all test1 objects created via `new test1()` a method called method1.  The second just adds a function to the constructor object.  In javascript, functions are objects which can have properties (including methods).

Answer (score 0):

The first version actually creates a method available to all objects instantiated like so:

```
var o = new test1();
o.test1();
```

The second simply attached a function as an attribute on the test2 function. If you're familiar with other class-based OO languages, this works kinda like a static method. You will not have access to the `this` pointer in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The first one:

```
var test1 = function () {
    this.method1 = function() {}
```

}

Defines the function "test1". Once (and only when) "test1" is called, "this.method1" will be defined as a function, that does nothing.

The second:

```
var test2 = function() {};
test2.method1 = function() {};
```

Create the function "test2" and at the same time defines the function "test2.method1", without the need to invoke the first function.

Answer (score 0):

The first one sets the method1 property on whatever invokes test1().

The second one defines an empty function and sets the method1 property on test2